# tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) is not called on GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gesture, gmsmapview

I am working on a `iOS/Swift 4.0` app where I created a `UITableView`, lets say *tableView* on a `GMSMapView`, lets say *mapView*. Initially the *tableView* was not visible and after setting `tableView.layer.zPosition = 2`, it was visible in front of the *mapView*. But gestures are not received by the *tableView* rather it was received by the *mapView*.

For example when I am trying to scroll the *tableView*, background *mapView* is moving/scrolling but the *tableView* is no. Also `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` is not called when I am selecting a cell. I have double checked the `datasource` and `delegate` is properly assigned and not being changed when reloading.

***Things I have tried:***

1. I disabled all gesture on the *mapView* when *tableView* is active (unhidden based on a `searchBar` state) using `self.mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)`
2. I have enabled tableViews, `isScrollEnabled`, `isUserInteractionEnabled`, `allowsSelection` properties true
3. I have set cells `selectionStyle` to `.default`, `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true

Still cant fix the issue, any step I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in different side and i suggest anyone to look below steps

1. Make sure that `tableView` is front to mapView if it was created in xcode statically
2. Make sure that the `tableView` is brought to front using `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: tableView)` if its created programmatically
3. Make sure that the size of the container of the tableView is fully cover the full size of the inner tableView
4. Enabled tableViews, `isScrollEnabled, isUserInteractionEnabled, allowsSelection` properties

Answer (score 1):

Moving layer up doesn't mean you're moving the whole view up. Try this instead:

```
view.insertSubview(tableView, above: mapView);
```

Regarding the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` check if you have `delegate` property set for the `UITableView` either in code or in xib/storyboard.